# Remove (symbolic link) item from "Favorites" menu from command line

Tags: windows-7, symbolic-link

When I say "Favorites", I am referring to the one on the left side of your Explorer window, not the Favorites folder located at C:\Users\username\Favorites.

[image]

I have a problem where on of the "favorite" items freezes anytime I click on it (had been a link to a network location which no longer exists).  If I right click on it to get 'properties" it freezes Explorer.  Where is this located on disk so I can remove it from the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those shortcuts are in the **Links** folder. If you username is `username`, the folder is at `C:\Users\username\Links`.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. Will give the answer-check when it lets me.